# Subquery to delete in android

Tags: android, mysql, sql, android-sqlite

I have a sqlitedatabase which definition is:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS carteras (" + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + "nombre_cartera  VARCHAR(30));");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS empresas (" + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + "nombre_empresa VARCHAR(30),"
            + "precio_actual DECIMAL(7));");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS operaciones (" +
             "fk_empresa INTEGER NOT NULL," +
             "fk_cartera INTEGER NOT NULL," +
             "cantidad INT(7)," +
             "precio_compra DECIMAL(7),"+
             "PRIMARY KEY (fk_empresa,fk_cartera)," +
             "FOREIGN KEY (fk_empresa) REFERENCES empresas(id)," + 
             "FOREIGN KEY (fk_cartera) REFERENCES carteras (id));");
```

In other activity I need to delete multiple chechbox items and I do this:

```
public void eliminar() {
        bd = base.getWritableDatabase();
        for (int i = 0; i < vals.size(); i++) {
            if(vals.get(i).isChecked()==true)
            {

//     String[] columns = {"id"};
//Cursor fila = bd.query("empresas", columns, "nombre_empresa=?", new String[] {vals.get(i).getEmpresa() }, null, null, null);
//bd.execSQL("delete from operaciones where fk_empresa IN (select e.nombre_empresa from empresas as e INNER JOIN operaciones fk_empresa=e.nombre_empresa where nombre_empresa="+vals.get(i).getEmpresa()+")", null);


Cursor fila = bd.rawQuery("delete from operaciones where fk_empresa IN (select e.nombre_empresa from empresas as e INNER JOIN operaciones fk_empresa=e.nombre_empresa where nombre_empresa="+vals.get(i).getEmpresa()+")", null);
                while (fila.moveToNext()) 
                {
                    aux=fila.getInt(0);
                    System.out.println(aux);
                }
//                cant=bd.delete("operaciones", "fk_empresa=" , null);
                //cant = bd.delete("operaciones", "id="+aux , null);    
            }

        }
        bd.close();

//        if (cant >= 1)
//        Toast.makeText(this, "Se borró la cartera con éxito",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        else
//        Toast.makeText(this, "Se produjo un error, vuelva a intentarlo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

The subquery doesn´t work. I proved with db.execSQL, db.rawQuery...and I don´t find the solution. In this final prove, the error in the console is: error near "=":syntax error, but it never worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I noticed you are deleting off of the fk. Did the full error say anything about a cascading delete?

Comment: No, it didn´t. The error is: android.database.sqlite.SqliteException:near "=": syntax error(code 1) while compiling: delete from operaciones where fk_empresa in(select e.nombre from empresas as e inner join operaciones fk_empresa=e.nombre_empresa where nombre_empresa='BBVA'

Answer (score 0):

```
where nombre_empresa="+vals.get(i).getEmpresa()+")"
```

Since `nombre_empresa` is a character field, then you need to use quotes around the value in conditions, i.e.

```
where nombre_empresa = '" + vals.get(i).getEmpresa() + "')"
```